# First time running PyCharm ChromeDriver test

Tags: python, selenium

So I have Python 2.7.10. I have Selenium 3.5.9. I have the current version of PyCharm and I set up the local interpreter. I am trying to run a unitest on my company's website and I am getting back:

> Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://www.rosoka.com/")

    def test_Login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        rosokaUsername = "*****@rosoka.com"
        rosokaPassword = "******"
        loginFieldID = "edit-name"
        passFieldID = "edit-pass"
        loginButtonXpath = "//input[@value ='Log in']"

        loginFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: find_element_by_id(loginFieldID))
        passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: find_element_by_id(passFieldID))
        loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))

        loginFieldElement.clear()
        loginFieldElement.send_keys(rosokaUsername)
        passFieldElement.clear()
        passFieldElement.send_keys(rosokapassword)
        loginButtonElement.click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Is anything happening other than the "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s" message?

Comment: How are you executing the test?

Answer (score 1):

The `if __name__ == '__main__'` block needs to be dedented. It is currently inside of your class.

Also, it looks like it should be `rosokaPassword` (camelCase) inside of `passFieldElement.send_keys(rosokapassword)`.

EDIT:

I modified the code and tested it on the website (although I don't have real credentials so I'll have to leave the rest to you). Selenium was having trouble finding the elements until I hovered over the "User Portal" link to make the dropdown appear.

```
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://www.rosoka.com/")

    def test_login(self):
        rosoka_username = "*****@rosoka.com"
        rosoka_password = "******"

        user_portal = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="om-leaf-om-u1-570991293-8"]/span/span')
        hover = ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(user_portal)
        hover.perform()

        login_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('edit-name')
        login_field.clear()
        login_field.send_keys(rosoka_username)

        pass_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('edit-pass')
        pass_field.clear()
        pass_field.send_keys(rosoka_password)

        login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('edit-submit')
        login_button.click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Got it, but it looks like it failed:           ERROR: test_Login (__main__.LoginTest)

  File "BasicActions.py", line 22, in test_Login
    loginFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: find_element_by_id(loginFieldID))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "BasicActions.py", line 22, in <lambda>
    loginFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: find_element_by_id(loginFieldID))
NameError: global name 'find_element_by_id' is not defined

Comment: @dsmith your tests are now running, it is up to you to debug them and get them to complete successfully. If you are running into more issues you cannot figure out, please ask another question.

Comment: @dsmith As this answer have catered to your main question of **`Ran 0 tests in 0.000s`** please accept the answer and raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer with the addition of wait time and screenshot:
import unittest
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.driver.get("https://www.rosoka.com")
    self.driver.save_screenshot('rosoka.png')
    time.sleep(10)

def test_login(self):
    rosoka_username = "****"
    rosoka_password = "***"

    user_portal = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="om-leaf-om-u1-570991293-8"]/span/span')
    hover = ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(user_portal)
    hover.perform()

    login_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('edit-name')
    login_field.clear()
    login_field.send_keys(rosoka_username)

    pass_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('edit-pass')
    pass_field.clear()
    pass_field.send_keys(rosoka_password)

    login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('edit-submit')
    login_button.click()
    time.sleep(10)


def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    unittest.main()